# PHP - Unexpected Else on line 60

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am trying to setup a panel for my game.

I have tried fixing it

```
<?php
$referer = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? _SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : 'undefined';
$agent = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] : 'undefined';

$address = 'undefined';

if (isset($_SERVER)) {
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
        $address = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    } elseif (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
        $address = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    } else {
        $address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
}

if ($address === '47.39.46.24') {


$host       = "localhost";
$dbusername = "asta";
$dbpassword = "***";
$dbname     = "asta";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli ($host, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
        . mysqli_connect_error());
} else {

  $roleid = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'roleid');
  $rolename = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'rolename');
  $rolepermission = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'rolepermission');
  $rolecolor = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'rolecolor');
  if (!empty($roleid)) {
    if (!empty($rolename)) {
    if (!empty($rolepermission)) {
        if (!empty($rolecolor)) {
        $sql    = "SELECT `id` FROM `roles` WHERE `id`='$roleid'";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        if ($result->num_rows >= 1) {
            echo "The role with id '$roleid' is already in the database.";
        } else {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO roles (id, name, permissions, color) values ('$roleid','$rolename','$rolepermission','$rolecolor')";
            if ($conn->query($sql)) {
                echo "The role '$rolename' has been created!!";
            } else {
                echo "Error: " . $sql . "" . $conn->error;
            }
            $conn->close();
       }} }
    } else {
        echo "ROLEID should not be empty";
        die();
    }
  } else {
    echo "ROLENAME should not be empty";
    die();
  }
    else {
    echo "ROLEPERMISSION should not be empty";
    die();
}

    else {
    echo "ROLECOLOR should not be empty";
    die();
}

}

}
?>
```

I expected it to handle the request..

Could someone please help? i am new to coding and you all have been a great help so far.

Again.. thanks for everything guys and girls

I am aware the code is vulnerable to SQL Injection. i will worry about that before the release of this.

Comment: Also, think about wrapping parts of your code in functions to make things cleaner. It's really hard to read the code like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You effectively have an `IF...ELSE...ELSE` statement due to closing off the `$rolepermission` block before an Else (line 51). Properly indenting your code should help with catching these by making the flow clearer.

Each `Else` also seems out of order. Check the code below to see if it runs as you'd expect:

```
<?php
$referer = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? _SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : 'undefined';
$agent = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] : 'undefined';

$address = 'undefined';

if (isset($_SERVER)) {
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
        $address = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    } elseif (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
        $address = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    } else {
        $address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
}

if ($address === '47.39.46.24') {


  $host       = "localhost";
  $dbusername = "asta";
  $dbpassword = "***";
  $dbname     = "asta";
  // Create connection
  $conn = new mysqli ($host, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);

  if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
      die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
        . mysqli_connect_error());
  } else {

    $roleid = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'roleid');
    $rolename = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'rolename');
    $rolepermission = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'rolepermission');
    $rolecolor = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'rolecolor');

    if (!empty($roleid)) {
      if (!empty($rolename)) {
        if (!empty($rolepermission)) {
          if (!empty($rolecolor)) {
            $sql    = "SELECT `id` FROM `roles` WHERE `id`='$roleid'";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);

            if ($result->num_rows >= 1) {
              echo "The role with id '$roleid' is already in the database.";
            } else {
              $sql = "INSERT INTO roles (id, name, permissions, color) values ('$roleid','$rolename','$rolepermission','$rolecolor')";

              if ($conn->query($sql)) {
                echo "The role '$rolename' has been created!!";
              } else {
                echo "Error: " . $sql . "" . $conn->error;
              }

              $conn->close();
            }
          }
          else {
            echo "ROLECOLOR should not be empty";
            die();
          }
        }
        else {
          echo "ROLEPERMISSION should not be empty";
          die();
        }
      }
      else {
        echo "ROLENAME should not be empty";
        die();
      }
    } 
    else {
      echo "ROLEID should not be empty";
      die();
    }
  }

}
?>
```